# Python - Make CSV with defined headers/footers from JSON response

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm making a call to an API and am getting back a response that looks like this:

```
'[{"time": 1477612800', ' "close": 5000', ' "high": 5000', ' "low": 
2100', ' "open": 2100', ' "volumefrom": 0.08311', ' "volumeto": 
414.42}', ' {"time": 1477699200', ' "close": 4000', ' "high": 30000', ' 
"low": 4000', ' "open": 12001', ' "volumefrom": 9.88', ' "volumeto": 
46066.49}', ...]'
```

What I want is to make a CSV that has each row be the 'time' value and the columns will be the rest of the values (close, open, high, low).

I'm pretty lost and most resources I have found assume that my data is being sent back in a different format. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You must convert your JSON to a tabular data structure (a lists of lists or a Pandas DataFrame) and then save that data structure as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON response seems not to be valid, there shouldn't be any single quotes inside of it. With the correct response, first you need to load the string to json:

```
import json
response_string = '[{"time": 1477612800, "close": 5000, "high": 5000, "low": 2100, "open": 2100, "volumefrom": 0.08311, "volumeto": 414.42}, ...]'
response_json = json.loads(response_string)
```

Then you can just print the values as they go (using Python 3.6 feature f-strings):

```
for item in response_json:
    print(f'{item["time"]},{item["close"]},{item["high"]},{item["low"]},{item["open"]},{item["volumefrom"]},{item["volumeto"]}')
```

or without f-strings (Python 3.5 and lower):

```
for item in response_json:
    print(item["time"] + ',' + item["close"] + ',' + item["high"] + ',' + item["low"] + ',' + item["open"] + ',' + item["volumefrom"] + ',' + item["volumeto"]')
```